# How to manage Ninject scope binding for objects used by both ASP.NET MVC and Quartz?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, quartz.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, which runs several scheduled jobs with Quartz.

The project uses Entity Framework with a repository pattern. And in my MVC project, the binding for the `AppContext` and `GenericRepository` are `InRequestScope`:

```
Bind<AppContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
Bind<IGenericRepository>().To<GenericRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

`GenericRepository` takes `AppContext` as its constructor argument, and the scoping here makes perfect sense for the MVC project. However the context and repository are also used by some of the Quartz jobs, and obviously, the above scope won't work for a Quartz job. For example:

```
public class SampleJob : IJob 
{
    public SampleJob(IGenericRepository repository)
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Here I need to inject `IGenericRepository` with a different scope, perhaps an `InThreadScope()`. And I can do that with conditional binding for `IGenericRepository` as follows:

```
Bind<IGenericRepository>()
    .To<GenericRepository>()
    .InThreadScope()
    .WhenInjectedInto<SampleJob>();
```

Great! That should work....

Nope, because the `AppContext` that is injected into `GenericRepository` will still be in `RequestScope`, so I need a conditional binding for `AppContext` too. But how?? I can't do `WhenInjectedInto` because `AppContext` will always be injected into `GenericRepository`.

Any idea? Or if there is a better way to manage Quartz job scopes in a MVC application please do share :)

Comment: Provide an `IGenericRepositoryFactory` to the Quartz side and manage the repository's lifespan as a local variable with `using` statements.

Comment: im sorry but could you elaborate more on this approach please? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject provides a generic `InScope()` method you can use to return your own custom object that defines the scope. I have used this in the past to first try to resolve a Request scope, and if there isn't one, return the current Thread as scope. this way you have a sort of "Hybrid" scope.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply Dave. But consider a scenario where it was able to resolve a Request scope (which is dependant on `HttpContext.Current` I believe), however during the execution of the job the request ended (`HttpContext` is disposed) even though the job might be still running. what will happen then?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` internally uses a `LogicalCallContext` which stores the HttpContext in a "logical" thread storage (which, unlike strict thread storage, flows across async tasks) preserves the HttpContext from the thread that created it. so if Quartz is creating the job, there won't be one, even if there are active web requests in the same process. otherwise, multiple requests in the same process would be overwriting `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, all this time I understood HttpContext in a wrong way. Now it makes much more sense and your answer will solve my problem perfectly. Thanks!